# Clicking a bootstrap 4 tab link causes angularJS controller to refresh

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I have a bizarre problem with bootstrap 4 tabs in an AngularJS app.
I built the tabs on the html page using this guide under 'Javascript Behaviour'
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/

The issue is when I click on one the tab links it causes the angular controller to refresh. 
I tried it with a default template in that bootstrap link to be sure it wasn't my own markup causing the problem.. but it still happened.

This is my markup anyway.. but like I said.. its the same problem if I use the one from the link.

Is there a solution to this or do I have to markup my tab a different way? I suspect bootstrap 4 JS is causing an issue with angularJS somehow..?

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is the href on your tab anchors. Remove it and see if everything still works.

Comment: The href is the issue yes, but if I take it off the tab doesn't work. I dont see why href would cause the constructor to reload..

Comment: The `bootstrap.js` library and the `angular.js` framework do not play well with each other. With  bootstrap3, one commonly used the third-pary library [Angular-UI Bootstrap Tabs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#tabs). Unfortunately that library has not been updated to bootstrap4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the `<a>` element with a `<span>` fixed the issue! :)